# Google App Engine, can people download my source code?? (with PHP)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE, and have big doutbts on how it works. Mainly the app.yaml configuration file. If i have this structure for example:

```
/
/index.php
/scripts/script.php
```

On app.yaml I should write something like this for example (the basic to work), right?

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /scripts/script.php
  script: scripts/script.php
```

Is this correct? And if i have a lot of scripts on the scripts directory, should i put an entry for all of them?

I ask this (I think its a really stupid question but i want to be sure) because i have realised that if i put the scripts directory as a static_dir, like:

```
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts
```

... if i go to the URL of that file (http://mydomain.com/scripts.script.php) i can download the source code.

So I guess that static_dir is not for accessing a whole directory's content, and as it's name says... is just for static content like photos for example, right? so for each script i should write a line on the app.yaml to be accesible?

Sorry about my stupid question, my english is not so good and i'm new at this so i have this doutbt ;)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put anything in `static` directories that you don't want the world to see. `static` directories are intended as a fast shortcut for serving things like images, CSS, and JavaScript.

.php files (or .py files if you're using Python) need to be 'executed' (evaluated) on the server (App Engine) side. Putting them in a `static_dir` puts them out of reach of the execution environment, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some detailed examples here of PHP and app.yaml here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

If you have a large number of *.php files that you want to make executable, you can use wildcards. For example:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Will map anything URL ending in .php to the equivalent filepath. So

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/some/directory/file.php
```

will map to

```
some/directory/file.php
```

in your app's directory.

Comment: I will have a look, I guessed it must be something like that.
Thank you very much!!